# Syntax for scraping double quotes in rapidminer (XPATH)

Tags: xpath, rapidminer

I'm having trouble using xpath in Rapidminer when trying to retrieve reviews form the google play store. The problem seems to be that these reviews are in double quotes and I can't get rapidminer to spit out the text...only blanks. I have a number of other xpath queries that are working fine for other commands where i use divs and span etc.  I'm able to get things to work on google spreadsheet for this query through =importXML, but not in rapidminer.
This is what I have in XPATH:

```
//*[@class='review-text']")
```

So I added a /text() to the end and still nothing. I have played around with adding //div instead of `//*` and have used h:/span also. I'm kind of hoping there's a special syntax for retrieving quotes that i'm unaware of?

Here is the HTML i'm looking to scrape in the image below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl6I8.png

Please see my comment below on further failed tests. Thanks.

Comment: The xpath seems correct but I don't know Rapidminer and don't see any relation between having quotation marks on the text and the inability to scrape. Try adding `/descendant-or-self::text` at the end. Not sure if having text mixed with tags at the div you want to scrape, could be an issue for Rapidminer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried that and no luck. It's weird, so games that have review content are coming up blank. Whereas games without content are coming up with a question mark. So, I believe it's working it's just not spitting out the content for me. This is what I tried: //h:div[@class='review-text']/descendant::text() and also //h* at the start. Any more ideas anyone?